# Writing data to csv or text file using python

Tags: python, csv, urllib2

I am trying to write some data to csv file by checking some condition as below

I will have a list of urls in a text file as below

**urls.txt**

```
www.example.com/3gusb_form.aspx?cid=mum
www.example_second.com/postpaid_mum.aspx?cid=mum
www.example_second.com/feedback.aspx?cid=mum
```

Now i will go through each url from the text file and read the content of the url using `urllib2` module in python and will search a string in the entire html page. If the required string founds i will write that url in to a csv file.

But when i am trying to write data(url) in to csv file,it is saving like each character in to one coloumn as below instead of saving entire url(data) in to one column

```
h   t   t   p   s   :   /   /   w   w   w......
```

**Code.py**

```
import urllib2
import csv

search_string = 'Listen Capcha'

html_urls = open('/path/to/input/file/urls.txt','r').readlines()
outputcsv = csv.writer(open('output/path' + 'urls_contaning _%s.csv'%search_string, "wb"),delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
outputcsv.writerow(['URL'])

for url in html_urls:
    url = url.replace('\n','').strip()
    if not len(url) == 0:
        req = urllib2.Request(url)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        if str(search_string) in response.read():
            outputcsv.writerow(url)
```

So whats wrong with the above code, what needs to be done in order to save the entire url(string) in to one column in a csv file ?

Also how can we write data to a text file as above ?

### Edited

Also i had a url suppose like `http://www.vodafone.in/Pages/tuesdayoffers_che.aspx` ,
this url will be redirected to `http://www.vodafone.in/pages/home_che.aspx?cid=che` in browser actually, but when i tried through code as below it is same as the above given url

```
import urllib2, httplib

httplib.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1  
request = urllib2.Request("http://www.vodafone.in/Pages/tuesdayoffers_che.aspx")
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
f = opener.open(request)
print f.geturl()
```

### Result

```
http://www.vodafone.in/pages/tuesdayoffers_che.aspx?cid=che
```

So finally how to catch the redirected url with urllib2 and fetch the data from it ?

Comment: You have your answer below.  However, there's little point to using CSV when you only have one column of data.  You could just open the file and write each url directly to it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you creating a one-column CSV file instead of just a plain sequence-of-lines text file?

Comment: k no problem of using text file, actually thats cool to use text file,but how to append data in to text file, because here when the first url contains the search string it will write to text file, and if second url contains the search string , defnitely the first url in the text file will overriden right ?

Comment: No, not if you open the file only once. That is, replace the `csv.writer` line with `outf = open(outfile, "w")`, and replace each `writerow` line with `outf.write("URL\n")` or `outf.write(url + "\n")`

Comment: Since you asked, you actually _can_ open files in append mode instead of plain write mode. But that's not the right solution to your problem; use @DavidRobinson's comment instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the last line to:

```
            outputcsv.writerow([url])
```

Comment: Thanks david that helped. Is there any other way of reading the urls other than urllib2 ?

Comment: Not unless it's not working for you. Is urllib2 missing something you need?

Comment: No its good to use urllilb2, i want to know other procedures that performs the same task, and some times i am getting the error as   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 366, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
httplib.BadStatusLine: '

Comment: Is there any alternative for urllib2 ?

Comment: Also whether urllib2 finds the redirected url automatically ?

Comment: That should be a separate, new question